# Is it possible to calculate this integral

Tags: calculus, integration

$$
\mbox{Is it possible to calculate this integral}\quad
\int{1 \over \cos^{3}\left(x\right) + \sin^{3}\left(x\right)}\,{\rm d}x\quad {\large ?}
$$

I have tried  $\dfrac{1}{\cos^3(x)+\sin^3(x)}$=$\dfrac{1}{(\cos(x)+\sin(x))(1-\cos x\sin x)}$ then I made a decomposition. But I'm still stuck.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F%28%28cos+x%29%5E3%2B%28sin+x%29%5E3%29) gets something that looks like it might help.  There are some imaginary terms in there, so the initial result is not correct.

Comment: Substituting $u=tan(x)$ and with some luck, you need to find a primitive of $$\frac{\sqrt{1+u^2}}{1+u^3}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you have left of $$I=\int\frac1{(\cos x+\sin x)(1-\sin x\cos x)}=\int\frac{\cos x+\sin x}{(1+2\sin x\cos x)(1-\sin x\cos x)}$$

Let  $\displaystyle\int(\cos x+\sin x)\ dx=\sin x-\cos x=u\implies u^2=1-2\sin x\cos x$

$$\implies I=\int\frac{2du}{(2-u^2)(1+u^2)}$$

Again, $\displaystyle\frac3{(2-u^2)(1+u^2)}=\frac{(2-u^2)+(1+u^2)}{(1+u^2)(2-u^2)}=\frac1{(1+u^2)}+\frac1{(2-u^2)}$

Finally use [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution#Integrals_containing_x2_.E2.88.92_a2) for the second integral and the first one is too simple to be described, right?

Comment: @yoda, how about this?

Comment: +1, There is a typo in the second integral: $$\frac1{(\cos x+\sin x)(1-\sin x\cos x)}=\frac{\cos x+\sin x}{(1+2\sin x\cos x)(1-\sin x\cos x)}.$$ Applying your substitution $u=\sin x-\cos x$ the integral $I$ becomes

$$\int \frac{2du}{\left( 2-u^{2}\right) \left( u^{2}+1\right) }.$$

Comment: @AméricoTavares, agreed & rectified. Thanks for your observation

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The substitution $u = \tan(\frac{x}{2})$ converts any integrand that is a rational function in the two variables $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ into a rational function in $u,$ which can then be integrated by standard methods. See p. 56 of Hardy's [**The Integration of Functions of a Single Variable**](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/38993/38993-pdf.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&{1 \over \bracks{\cos\pars{x} + \sin\pars{x}}\bracks{1 - \cos\pars{x}\sin\pars{x}}}
={1 \over \bracks{\cos\pars{x} + \tan\pars{\pi/4}\sin\pars{x}}
\bracks{1 - \sin\pars{2x}/2}}
\\[3mm]&={\root{2} \over \cos\pars{x - \pi/4}\bracks{2 - \sin\pars{2x}}}
={\root{2} \over \cos\pars{x - \pi/4}\braces{2 - \sin\pars{2\bracks{x - \pi/4} + \pi/2}}}
\\[3mm]&={\root{2} \over \cos\pars{x - \pi/4}\braces{2 - \cos\pars{2\bracks{x - \pi/4}}}}
\end{align}

> With $t \equiv x - \pi/4$:
>   \begin{align}
> &{1 \over \bracks{\cos\pars{x} + \sin\pars{x}}\bracks{1 - \cos\pars{x}\sin\pars{x}}}
> ={\root{2} \over \cos\pars{t}\bracks{2 - \cos\pars{2t}}}
> ={\root{2} \over \cos\pars{t}\braces{2 - \bracks{2\cos^2\pars{t} - 1}}}
> \\[3mm]&={\root{2} \over \cos\pars{t}\bracks{3 - 2\cos^2\pars{t}}}
> ={\root{2} \over 2}\,
> {1 \over \cos\pars{t}\bracks{\root{3}/2 - \cos\pars{t}}\bracks{\root{3}/2 + \cos\pars{t}}}
> \\[3mm]&={\root{2} \over 2}\bracks{%
> {4/3\over \cos\pars{t}} + {3/2 \over \root{3}/2 - \cos\pars{t}} +
>  {3/2 \over \root{3}/2 + \cos\pars{t}}}
> \\[3mm]&={2\root{2} \over 3}\,{1 \over \cos\pars{t}}
> +{3\root{2} \over 4}\bracks{%
> {1 \over \root{3}/2 - \cos\pars{t}} + {1 \over \root{3}/2 + \cos\pars{t}}
> }
> \end{align}

$$
\int{\dd t \over \cos\pars{t}}=\ln\pars{\sec\pars{t} + \tan\pars{t}} +\quad \mbox{a constant}
$$

> The remaining integrals can be easily performed with $s \equiv \tan\pars{t/2}$.

Comment: @ Felix Martin.Thank you.